# Github Doesn't Recognize JQuery Image Height

Tags: image, github, loading

I'm working with a function that uses an image to set a div's `margin-top`.

It finds the image height and the window height and sets the divs margin-top to the lesser of the two values. It works perfectly fine for all local browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox).

When I upload it to GitHub it fails to recognize the image height however. Now when I run the code below on GitHub the `console.log` of the image height is `0`.  When I run it locally the `console.log` of the image height is correct. The image is loaded on GitHub, so it's not an issue of the image not making into the web page.

It seems like the script runs before the image loads on GitHub, but not locally. Anyone have any ideas?

```js
var portfolioMargin = function() {
 var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
 var imageHeight = $('#imageWrap img').height();
 //if windowheight is bigger than image height make portfolio div margin equal to           image height, else do the opposite
 console.log("window height " + windowHeight);
 console.log("image height " + imageHeight);
 if (windowHeight > imageHeight) {
  $('#portfolio').css('margin-top', imageHeight);
 } else {
  
  $('#portfolio').css('margin-top', windowHeight);
 }
};//end portfolioMargin function
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out I think.  You have to wrap the function in a window.load function to make sure all images have been loaded.  From what I understand this won't work for dynamically added images however.  Here is the code that fixed it:

```js
//make sure images have loaded before running image height
$(window).load(function() {
 portfolioMargin();
});
```